# Get array of available column names from model in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I was wondering if there was a way to get all available column names and put them in an array as symbols?

Lets say that the table looks like this (taken from schema.rb):

```
t.integer  "inst_number"
t.string   "name"
t.string   "street"
t.integer  "postcode"
t.string   "city"
```

Right now I have a method withtin the corresponding model where I define:

```
def self.attributes
    [
      :inst_number,
      :name,
      :street,
      :postcode,
      :city
    ].freeze
end
```

Is there a way to get them listet in an array so I don't have to manually update self.attributes every time I do a migration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose the table name is 'users' & model name is `User`

You can get the array o column names using

```
User.column_names # This gives array of strings of column names
```

To get it as symbols

```
User.column_names.map(&:to_sym)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a better solution might be the [annotate](https://rubygems.org/gems/annotate) gem.  It does exactly what you're looking to do and all you need to do is install it:

```
#gemfile
gem "annotate", "~> 2.6.0"
```

or

```
#command line
gem install annotate
```

then run `annotate`

it automatically updates your models attributes in each `'model'.rb` file.  If you make a change, just run annotate again - or even better set up a rake task to run it with each migration.